# How to set Directory for a specific country in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, routing, virtualhost, httpd

So I need to set a `VirtualHost` that have one domain to route clients to different applications depending on their IP address.

For example I want an american user that visits `example.com` to be served from `/path/to/usa/application` while users from different countries should be served from `/new/international/application/path`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with [mod_geoip](http://www.maxmind.com/app/mod_geoip) and [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Something like the following should do the trick:

```
DocumentRoot /new/international/application/path

GeoIPEnable On
GeoIPDBFile path-to-geoip.dat

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^US$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /path/to/usa/application/$1 [L]
```

Requests from an IP address which the geoip module classifies as being in the US will be served from `/path/to/usa/application`, whereas other requests will be served from the default document root.